# How to turn a DataFrame column of binary variables into multiple columns of dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, binary, dummy-variable

This should be an easy question, but for some reason I can't find the answer online. I have a DataFrame column that consists of dummy variables:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.Series([6,7,8,3])
foo1 = bob.apply(lambda x: bin(x)[2:].zfill(4))
foo1

0    0110
1    0111
2    1000
3    0011
```

What I want is a 4x4 data frame that looks like

```
A B C D
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
```

I've tried using get_dummies to no results:

```
foo1.str.get_dummies()

0110 0111 1000 0011
1    0    0    0
0    1    0    0
0    0    1    0
0    0    0    1
```

str.split and making the column into a series of lists doesn't work either. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# convert the series to str type; 
# extract all characters with regex .; 
# unstack to wide format
foo1.astype(str).str.extractall('(.)')[0].unstack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will skip your initial step of `foo` to `foo1` and get you straight there from `foo`

```
foo.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list('{:04b}'.format(x))))

   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [49]: pd.DataFrame(foo1.apply(list).values.tolist())
Out[49]:
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  1
```